# Detecting if a function is called too many times in a short interval

Tags: php, session-variables

I'm not sure if this is possible but thought I would ask anyway.

I am developing a wordpress based website that already has quite a bit of data in the database.

As I write new code for the site I use a function I've written (getDebug) to 'email' myself what is happening in the code.

A few times now (due to either carelessness or ignorance) I've left my debug function in recursive loops that loop through every 'post' in the database. The result is that I lock up my test site whilst it happily sends me 10,000 emails.

I wondered if it is possible to detect how many times a function has been called within a certain time-span and if it exceeds a number then stop performing the action.

I wondered if this could be done with sessions?

Here's an example:

```
foreach($allPostIDs as $postID) {
 getDebug("Check postID ".$postID); // oops, I'm going to email on each iteration
 // rest of foreach....
}
```

I know the following won't work but this gives you an idea of what I would like to do (unless there is a better way of achieving this):

```
/* ======================================================= */
// SENDS AN EMAIL TO ADMIN WITH DEBUG INFO
/* ======================================================= */
if (!function_exists('getDebug')) {
    function getDebug($var = null, $extraInfo = null) {
        if(
          $_SESSION("HowManyTimesCalled") < 10 && 
          $_SESSION("TimeSinceLastCall") > 10
         ) {
            $adminEmail = new FAR_Email_Class();
            $adminEmail->addDebugVar($var);
            $adminEmail->addExtraInfo($extraInfo);
            $adminEmail->sendEmail();
        }
            $_SESSION("HowManyTimesCalled")++;
            $_SESSION("TimeSinceLastCall") = time();
    }
}
/* ======================================================= */
// END OF FUNCTION
/* ======================================================= */
```

I'm not sure if the $_SESSION vars would be updated though if the browser isn't refreshed?

Any ideas on how to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're wanting to detect how many times for a single user, $_SESSION could work.

If you want to detect how many times across all users (sessions), you'll need to store it in the db or on the filesystem or in a memory cache like redis.